# I am trying to update the data but it's not working

Tags: c#, ms-access

I make a program that saves and updates data from the Access database, I can save and read data, and I can also update but the problem is when I try to update data it goes to the second condition "Data Not Updated". I have added my code, if there is any mistake then please help me to solve it.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Data.OleDb;
    
    namespace qasimpos
    {
        public partial class Form9 : Form
        {
            string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\pos.accdb;Persist Security Info=True";
            string nname, ddate, ccompany, pparty, oorder, kkg, PpCS, ppprice, ccprice, wwprice, rrprice, bbilln, qquantity;
            
    
            private void btnclose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
    
            private void btnup_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                nname = textBox1.Text;
                ddate = textBox2.Text;
                ccompany = textBox3.Text;
                pparty = textBox4.Text;
                oorder = textBox5.Text;
                kkg = textBox6.Text;
                PpCS = textBox7.Text;
                ppprice = textBox8.Text;
                ccprice = textBox9.Text;
                wwprice = textBox10.Text;
                rrprice = textBox11.Text;
                bbilln = textBox12.Text;
                qquantity = textBox13.Text;
    
                //SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
                OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
                connection.Open();
                try
                {
                    string query = "UPDATE prod SET tareekh=@tareekh,company=@company,party=@party,hukam=@hukam,kg=@kg,PCS=@PCS,pprice=@pprice,cprice=@cprice,wprice=@wprice,rprice=@rprice,billn=@billn,quantity=@quantity WHERE namee=@namee";
                    //SqlCommand cmmd = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
                    OleDbCommand cmmd = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@namee", nname);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tareekh", ddate);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@company", ccompany);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@party", pparty);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@hukam", oorder);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@kg", kkg);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PCS", PpCS);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pprice", ppprice);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cprice", ccprice);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@wprice", wwprice);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rprice", rrprice);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@billn", bbilln);
                    cmmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quantity", qquantity);
    
                    int result = cmmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result > 0)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Data Updated Successfully ");
                        this.Close();
                        
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Data Not Updated");
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    connection.Close();
                }
    
    
            }
    
            private void textBox12_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
    
            }
    
            private void Form9_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                textBox1.Text = nname;
                textBox2.Text = ddate;
                textBox3.Text = ccompany;
                textBox4.Text = pparty;
                textBox5.Text = oorder;
                textBox6.Text = kkg;
                textBox7.Text = PpCS;
                textBox8.Text = ppprice;
                textBox9.Text = ccprice;
                textBox10.Text = wwprice;
                textBox11.Text = rrprice;
                textBox12.Text = bbilln;
                textBox13.Text = qquantity;
            }
    
            public Form9(string namee,string tareekh,string company,string party,string hukam,string kg,string PCS,string pprice,string cprice,string wprice,string rprice,string billn,string quantity)
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                nname = namee;
                ddate = tareekh;
                ccompany = company;
                pparty = party;
                oorder = hukam;
                kkg = kg;
                PpCS = PCS;
                ppprice = pprice;
                ccprice = cprice;
                wwprice = wprice;
                rrprice = rprice;
                bbilln = billn;
                qquantity = quantity;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this you also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69602589/i-am-trying-to-update-data-but-its-not-working-please-help-me-where-i-am-doing#comment123027368_69602589?

Comment: You must add the parameters in the same order as they are in your sql statement. So move AddWithValue("@namee", nname) to the last position

Comment: its working now Thanks

Comment: You are adding everything as text. You must respect the data types of the fields of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Parameters should be same as mentioned in the query.

Please find below content directly from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters?redirectedfrom=MSDN#System_Data_OleDb_OleDbCommand_Parameters)

> The OLE DB .NET Provider does not support named parameters for passing
> parameters to an SQL statement or a stored procedure called by an
> OleDbCommand when CommandType is set to Text. In this case, the
> question mark (?) placeholder must be used. For example: SELECT * FROM
> Customers WHERE CustomerID = ? Therefore, the order in which
> OleDbParameter objects are added to the OleDbParameterCollection must
> directly correspond to the position of the question mark placeholder
> for the parameter in the command text.